# Rspec test for whether a model was locked for updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm wondering if there is a specific rspec test that can verify whether a model was pessimistically locked or not for updating. You can check if a model was changed, or get the previous values but is there anyway to determine if at some point during an operation in question, using active record if a model was locked for updating?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there's no way to test whether a model was locked by `Locking::Pessimistic` since it's actually the `database row level lock` such as `FOR UPDATE` and Rails will not know about what happen at the database level.

For example, when you call `p = Product.lock.find(1)` this will execute the database query `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and does not cache anything about that query (lock or anything else), so object p here is nothing but an instance of the Product model. The database will take care all the lock mechanize (other transactions will be blocked until the current transaction ends), Rails do nothing at this time.

However, when Rails generate the query `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, Rails use the `ActiveRecord::Relation#lock` method, so you could test whether an instance of model was locked by test the Relation which query that model instead.

```rb
x = Product.lock # Relation
x.locked? # true
s = x.find(1)
s.locked? # undefined method

# test that the Product call `:lock`
expect(Product).to receive(:lock)

# test that a Product Relation call `:lock`
expect_any_instance_of(ActiveRecord::Relation).to receive(:lock)
Product.where(id: 1).lock.all
```